# TypeScript Compile Error Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: typescript, code-translation

error message after transpiling code below:

> [tsc] > C:/Workarea/MyFirstAngular/src/enum/msg.ts(35,33): error
> TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
> Failed to compile TypeScript: Error: tsc command has exited
> with code:2

```
module MessageUtil {
    enum Morning {
    "Good Morning",
    "Great to see you!",
    "Good day.",
    "Lovely day today, isn't it?",
    "What's up?",
    "Nice to meet you",
}
}
    export class MessageData {
        private getRandomElementOfEnum(e : any):string{
            var length:number = Object.keys(e).length();  //<-- This is Line 35
            return e[Math.floor((Math.random() * length)+1)];
        }
        public getRandMorning():string {
            return this.getRandomElementOfEnum(Morning);
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know what's my exact fault?

My Setup:
-IDEA 14
-Node.js
-Gulp
-gulp-tsc
-gulp-connect (for Livereload)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Guys who have same error message --> Check your Code-Syntax

Found my fault. This is **not** Java.

> ```
>  private getRandomElementOfEnum(e : any):string{
>       var length:number = Object.keys(e).length();  //<-- This is Line 35
>       return e[Math.floor((Math.random() * length)+1)];
>  }
> ```

Should be:

```
    private getRandomElementOfEnum(e : any):string{
        var length:number = Object.keys(e).length;  // <--- WITHOUT ()
        return e[Math.floor((Math.random() * length)+1)];
    }
```

Comment: Did the exact same thing and was sat there stairing at it for about 20 minutes wondering...